# C# - DatagidView show full header text

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagrid in my application. My datagridview columns have very long names and I would like that datagridview would show full text of the column header. I have tried change `AutoSizeColumnMode` property to `ColumnHeader`, but I do that then I wont be able to resize the columns, I wont be able to make the cell bigger or smaller.

Wich properties should I change so that my datagridview shows full text on the columns?

Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Winform designer leave the `AutoSizeColumnMode` setting to `ColumnHeader`, but in your form's constructor (after calling `InitializeComponent()`) set all your DGV columns `AutoSizeColumnMode` property to `None`:

```
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns) {
        col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
    }
```

When your form loads your DGV Columns will be sized to the column header but your users will be able to resize column widths.